# How do I keep an extension script running after the popup window is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So lets say I am making an addon/extension for firefox/chrome.  I have a popup with one button.  It looks like this:

[image]

When the button is clicked I want some function to execute, and I want it to *continue to execute* even after the popup loses focus and disappears.

The normal behavior is to close the popup as soon as it loses focus.  So if I click the button then immediately click something else, the popup disappears and I get this message in the console:

```
Cannot send function call result: other side closed connection (calldata:
({path:"bookmarks.getTree", args:[]}))
```

No error checking or using onbeforeunload works.

Here's a minimal example:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "delete bookmarks",
    "version": "0.1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["management", "bookmarks", "http://*/"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["doStuff.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["doStuff.js"]
    }]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <button id="doStuff">doStuff</button>
    <script src="doStuff.js"></script>
</html>
```

**doStuff.js**

```
var button = document.getElementById("doStuff");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  doStuff();
}, false); 

function doStuff(){
  chrome.bookmarks.getTree(deleteAllBookmarks);
}

function deleteAllBookmarks(result){  //JUST AN EXAMPLE!
 //delete/remove ALL bookmarks
  for(var i = 0 ; i < result[0].children.length; i ++){  //get children of root 
    var child = result[0].children[i];
    for(var j = 0 ; j < child.children.length; j++){  //get children of children of root 
      var childchild = child.children[j];
      console.log("deleting id " + childchild.id);
      chrome.bookmarks.removeTree(childchild.id, success);  //delete everything
    }
  }
}

function success(result){
  alert("Success");
}
```

So, again, I am trying to finish executing javascript code even after the parent html page is closed.  It seems like this should be easy, since I am loading the script both as a content_script and a background script, but I cannot figure it out and there are no matching SO posts.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same JS file for your popup js, your background script and your content script. You'd be better off having one file for each purpose. Then your popup trigger detects the click on the button, sends a message to the background script that do the long processing, and can send a message back to the popup. Have a look at my answer here, where I explain this process, it should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782412/promise-resolve-not-called-because-popup-closes-too-fast/50992264#50992264

Answer (score 1):

You should [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) of chrome.
When press button, `popup` will send message to `background`, and `background` will listen and do something.

You can't do it if just use `popup page`.
And if you want to do something with `active page`, you need create listener in that page (add script with `content_scripts`).